# Create a linked-list with chars from a string with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have to write a recursive function that has in input a string and create a linked-list structure that rapresents it (so the info parameter of each record has a character of the string).
when I run the test it does nothing so I cannot understand where is the error, can you help me?

**linked-list structure:**

```
typedef char TipoInfoSCL;

struct ElemSCL {
  TipoInfoSCL info;
  struct ElemSCL *next;
  };

typedef struct ElemSCL TipoNodoSCL;
typedef TipoNodoSCL * TipoSCL;
```

**Function**

```
TipoSCL sclstrings_create (const char *scl)
{
    TipoSCL ris;
    if  (ris == NULL)
    {
        ris->info = '\0';
        ris = NULL;
        return ris;
    }
    else
    {
        TipoSCL ris = (TipoNodoSCL*) malloc (sizeof(TipoNodoSCL));
        ris->next = ris;
        ris->info = scl[0]; 
        return sclstrings_create(scl + 1);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
void printList(TipoSCL l);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   TipoSCL scl;
   char *str = "Hello World";
   scl = sclstrings_create(str);
   sclstrings_print(scl) ;

   return 0;
}

void printList(TipoSCL l)
{
   
   TipoSCL aux = l;
   int pos = 0;
   while (aux != NULL)
   {
       printf("pos: %d, info: %c\n", pos, aux->info);
       aux = aux->next;
       pos++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't don typedefs like `typedef TipoNodoSCL * TipoSCL`. Hiding a pointer type with a typedef only adds confusion. Also [edit] and show a [mcve] instead of individual code snippets that we must stitch together.

Comment: Well done giving your test code, but please turn it in to a [mre]. Also, please take the [tour] and read  [ask] for general advice. You might get comments recommending to use a debugger. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Did you?

Comment: Your code has no definition of `sclstrings_print`. On the other had, `printList` is defined, but never called.

Comment: `if (ris == NULL)` : here `ris` is uninitialized. IOW `ris` contains a undetermined value.

Comment: `ris = malloc(sizeof(TipoNodoSCL)); ris->next = ris;` makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Please [edit] and show the output you expect. Is it `pos: 0, info: H` `pos: 1, info: e`  etc.?

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be some assignment. I will just point out some problems your code has and a general idea how you could implement what you want.

First: The if condition `ris == NULL` in the `sclstrings_create` function does not what you expect. Since `ris` ist defined as `TipoSCL ris;` and `TipoSCL` is an alias for `ElemSCL*`. The variable `ris` holds a pointer to some `ElemSCL` value. But since you didn't initilaized `ris` it can have any value. So the code `if (res == null) { ... } else { ... }` is unstable and leads to undefined behaviour.

Second: In the expression `ris->next = ris;` you create a circula reference which can make sense, but doesn't in yours.

The Idea:

The idea of the function `sclstrings_create(char* str)` is that it returns a pointer to a linked list which holds all the `char`s of the string.
So the recursive idea is to check if the given string is empty, if yes return `NULL`, if no then call `sclstrings_create` with `str + 1` to get a linke list of the string expect for the first `char`. Then pack the first `char` in an list element and set the `next` field to the recursively create list and return the pointer to your created list element.

Answer (score 0):

Within the function `sclstrings_create` there is declared a local uninitialized variable

```
TipoSCL ris;
```

So the next if statement where the local variable is used

```
if  (ris == NULL)
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the subsstatements of the if statement

```
if  (ris == NULL)
{
    ris->info = '\0';
    ris = NULL;
    return ris;
}
```

do not make a sense because in this case the function returns a null pointer and invoke undefined behavior because there is also used a null pointer to access memory.

The else part of the if statement is also logically incorrect

```
else
{
    TipoSCL ris = (TipoNodoSCL*) malloc (sizeof(TipoNodoSCL));
    ris->next = ris;
    ris->info = scl[0]; 
    return sclstrings_create(scl + 1);
}
```

For example you allocated a node that does not appended to the list because it points to itself

```
    ris->next = ris;
```

And the function return pointer to another node

```
    return sclstrings_create(scl + 1);
```

that produces memory leaks.

The function can be defined the following way

```
TipoSCL sclstrings_create( const char *scl )
{
    if ( *scl == '\0' )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        TipoSCL ris = malloc( sizeof( TipoNodoSCL ) );
        ris->info = *scl; 
        ris->next = sclstrings_create( scl + 1 );
        return ris;
    }
}
```

And it seems there is a typo in the function name in its definition

```
void printList(TipoSCL l)
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

There must be

```
void sclstrings_print(TipoSCL l)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```